# How to merge an IEnumerable into a ReactiveList and remove the duplicated items?

Tags: c#, linq, reactiveui

I have a `ReactiveList<Monitor> Monitors`, and an `IEnumerable<Monitor> newMonitors`. Inside the Monitor, there is a unique SN defined:

```
public class Monitor
{
    public string SN {get;set;}//unique
}

ReactiveList<Monitor> Monitors
IEnumerable<Monitor> newMonitors
```

Now I want to merge the `newMonitors` into `Monitors` and remove the duplicated items by `SN`.

I am trying to use the method provided by `ReactiveList` rather than general LINQ because I want to keep the notification of `ReactiveList` and its `DerivedCollection` which are used in my binding.

My current solution is to check if the items already exists and add it one by one, like

```
foreach (var m in newMonitors)
{
    if(Monitors.Contains(m))//to override the comparison operators here
        continue;
    else
        Monitors.Add(m);
}
```

I think the performance will be low when newMonitors's count could be thousands.

Any other elegant way to do this?

Fei

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a hashset and keep track of the keys that have been added in parallel, only pain will be when you add or remove need to make sure you are removing from both collections

Put in your class member variable

```
private readonly HashSet<string> _monitorSet = new HashSet<string>();
```

Then in your loop

```
foreach (var m in newMonitors)
{
    if(_monitorSet.Contains(m.SN))
        continue;
    else
    {
        _monitorSet.Add(m.SN);
        Monitors.Add(m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that code snippet there's two options I can think of:

1. Have `ReactiveList` internally make use of an `ISet` (probably `HashSet for it's Monitor 'list' here) then it will make use of hash codes to compare for an O(nlog(n)) or thereabouts insertion time. Of course Monitor would need to override GetHashCode() and Equals()! You can probably work something out with Properties, getters and setters to fiddle this to your needs.
2. If you can't do this then O(nn) insertion time is the best you've got (without building your own custom insertion/tracking code) BUT is probably okay as long as your comparison code is simple, in the case of string comparison only on SN, I wouldn't be too concerned about the speed but note the below.

Make sure you do not use the default operator == when comparing Strings in performace critical (and non-language related) scenarios, there are some topics on faster String comparisons on SO elsewhere :P